# Prerender React app as static HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, react-server

I have an interactive landing page (single page - no react router). This landing page will need to be uploaded to a CMS where you just paste in the HTML - meaning I do not need `<html> <head> <body>` tags and the JavaScript file is uploaded separately. Currently I can just paste `<div id="react-root"></div>` into the CMS and upload my bundled JavaScript file and the page works.

However, the feedback is that this page now needs be be crawlable on all search engines. This means I need to basically render the initial HTML generated by react to paste into the CMS and have the page still all work as expected.

I am trying to make my build command output the rendered HTML to an index.html file where I can copy and paste the code into the CMS. (I have got my bundle.js file working fine).

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
  ],
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      template: require('./src/template.js'),
    })
  ]
});
```

**template.js**

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const LandingPage = require('./App.js');
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(LandingPage);

module.exports = function () {
  return ReactDOM.hydrate(html, document.getElementById('lp-root'));
};
```

So I have used react-dom-server to renderToString. Is this the best way to do this? If so, this way isn't working as HtmlWebpackPlugin cannot process the ES6 syntax used in the landing pages (import and exports) - anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

The approach seems correct.
However, you might need babel transpiler to convert your code from ES6 syntax.
Try adding a new rule in the webpack config for the js/jsx files.
Something like this:

```
  {
    test: /js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    query: { presets: ["react", "es2016", "es2015"], plugins: ["transform-class-properties"] },
  },
```

It will transpile your code properly before using.

Hope it helps.
Please revert for any doubts.

Comment: I actually do have babel in my config (I have updated my question with the common webpack config that is used for both prod and dev). However I still get syntax error "import" so it seems that the HtmlWebpackPlugin is out of scope for bable?

Comment: You also need to give presets and plugins to babel config. Babel is just a transpiler. You also need to give plugins which babel uses to transform the new syntax into the format readable by browser. E.g., the query which I have provided in the answer have es2016 preset given. It will help babel to transform the es2016 syntax in browser readable format. Try adding the above query also for js/jsx files.